# Routes and index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Articles controller, I have the following index method:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

And in my routes.rb I have this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles, only: [:index]
end
```

This nicely gives me a route like this: localhost:3000/users/2/articles

But instead of showing a list of articles by user 2, it still shows all of them. What do I need to do to my index action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index action you should filter the articles you fetch by the `user_id` parameter:

```
def index
  @articles = if params[:user_id]
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    user.articles
  else
    Article.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool. That works for /users/2/articles. Is there a way to still show all of them if they hit /articles?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution. All you need to do is first check for the `user_id` parameter, and if it isn't there you don't want to filter by user and if it is you filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@articles = @user.articles
```